Connect to Azure API Management from Sharepoint framework
We have an existing Sharepoint framework (SPFx) environment, with multiple SPFx solutions, where we use AadHttpClient from @microsoft/sp-http to connect to an Azure AD secured API (App service), using delegated access, i.e user_impersonation scope.
We also have an Azure API Management instance (APIM), which includes an API from the mentioned backend. Now we are tasked with rerouting the SPFx solutions to connect via APIM, instead of directly to the App Service.
We already serve connections via APIM using subscription keys. However, we are looking for a way to connect our SPFx solutions using Entra ID managed identities.
In APIM access control (IAM) center, we gave the SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal (SOCEWAP) a Reader role.
Then we uploaded a SPFx solution with the following addition to package_solution.json
{
        "resource": "<APIM Enterprise application name>",
        "scope": "Reader"
}


, and (simplified)
aadHttpClientFactory.getClient(
      // APIM Enterprise application ID
    );

in code.
This API permission request showed up in the Sharepoint Admin center as expected, and after granting it showed up in the SPO principal, but with Delegated type. We tried connecting but got a token error message in the console during debugging.
In the SOCEWAP app registration, we have also been looking for a way to manually add a permission to the APIM API, but we can not find any reference to either APIM or any specific APIM API. All we have there under 'My APIs' are the ones with an app registration. We have thought about adding an app registration for the APIM API, but we can not find any reference to this in the documentation.
How do we connect to an APIM API from a SPFx solution, using Entra ID managed identities?
